# Does anyone know of a good free bulk upload tool for web apps?

Tags: javascript, flash, upload, bulk

I have a web application in which a user has to upload images to a gallery. At the moment they need to upload one image at a time so it's pretty tedious.

I'd like to implement a system where they could potentially drag and drop files into the browser, or select a folder to upload.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

(By the way; it's a .Net App if it makes a difference, but I was thinking most of the work would be happening client side so shouldn't matter)

-Ev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SWFUpload**](http://www.swfupload.org/) is pretty nice. It can select multiple images in the select dialog. It relies on Flash.

There are a number of other Flash-based uploaders around (they all make use of Flash's upload capabilities, which in addition to bulk uploads include things like progress bars, client-side resizing (Flash 10+) and file type filters (*.jpg,*.gif)... SWFUpload is certainly one of the most complete solutions.

Comment: @Josh but only by a few seconds. :)

Comment: Why did I waste time looking for a screen cap? :-) Anyway +1 for you

Comment: Thanks guys I'll check this out and hopefully accept the answetr

Comment: @Pekka웃 This answer being more than 4 years old I am wondering what you would recommend today.

Answer (score 1):

Is [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) the kind of thing you're looking for?

From their site:

> SWFUpload is a small JavaScript/Flash
>   library to get the best of both
>   worlds. It features the great upload
>   capabilities of Flash and the
>   accessibility and ease of HTML/CSS.
>   See it in action.... Upload multiple
>   files at once by ctrl/shift-selecting
>   in dialog Javascript callbacks on all
>   events Get file information before
>   upload starts Style upload elements
>   with XHTML and css Display information
>   while files are uploading using HTML
>   No page reloads necessary Works on all
>   platforms/browsers that has Flash
>   support. Degrades gracefully to normal
>   HTML upload form if Flash or
>   javascript is unavailable Control
>   filesize before upload starts Only
>   display chosen filetypes in dialog
>   Queue uploads, remove/add files before
>   starting upload

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Plupload. It's open source and has modules withing with Flash, Silverlight, HTML5 and HTML5. Depending on module used, it supports file upload using drag & drop, upload queue, client-side image resize, etc.

http://www.plupload.com/